# how to get unique values in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have a table like below

```
event_date    id     
----------    ---  
2015-11-18    x1
2015-11-18    x2
2015-11-18    x3
2015-11-18    x4
2015-11-18    x5
2015-11-19    x1
2015-11-19    x2
2015-11-19    y1
2015-11-19    y2
2015-11-19    y3
2015-11-20    x1
2015-11-20    y1
2015-11-20    z1
2015-11-20    z2
```

**Question**: How to get unique count of id for every date (such that we get count of only those id which were not seen in the previous records)? Something like this:

```
event_date    count(id)
-----------   ---------
2015-11-18      5
2015-11-19      3
2015-11-20      2
```

Each ID should only be counted once regardless of whether it occurs within the same date group or otherwise.

Comment: Tag the dbms used please.

Comment: Are you running MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an answer that'll work although I am not sure I like it:

```
select t.event_date,
       count(1)
from ( 
      -- Record first occurrence of each id along with the earliest date occurred 
      select id,
              min(event_date) as event_date
       from
       mytable
       group by id
      ) t
group by t.event_date;
```

I know it works because I tested with your data to get the results you wanted.

This actually works for this data but if you had a date group that consisted only of duplicate ids, for example, if among rows, you had one more row `('2016-01-01', 'z2')` this won't display any records for that `2016-01-01` because `z2` is a duplicate. If you need to return a row within your results:

> 2016-01-01    0

then, you have to use a LEFT JOIN with the GROUP BY.

## [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c2e79/6/0) here

Comment: are you sure, you tested it? Your inner query doesn't seems correct at all. Take a look at the inner GROUP BY.

Comment: Yes, I tested it but on MySQL although it shouldn't be different. The inner query ensures that each id only occurs once in the data, but like I said, watch out for the edge conditions when you expect 0 to be the count for certain dates.

Comment: SQL92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: That can be a problem for older versions but I am guessing (not sure) can be solved using `min`

Comment: Yes, It can be solved using min.   { select t.event_date,
       count(1)
from ( 
       select id,
              min(event_date)
       from
       mytable
       group by id
      ) t
group by t.event_date }

Comment: Correct. MIN was necessary to make this query work. Before it was not guaranteed to give correct results in MySQL as the date was only arbitrarily chosen per group, and was invalid in other DBMS. Now it's a very good solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could group by the date and apply a distinct count to the id per group:

```
SELECT   event_date, COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY event_date
```

Comment: This doesn't address the repeated ids, as it would only remove ids *within* a date rather than *across* dates.

Comment: above comment is absolutely correct! To clarify, here an ID will be called a UNIQUE if it has never been seen in the previous dates.

Comment: I don't understand why people are upvoting a wrong answer. Are they even reading the question?

Comment: @freetiger, I mistook the question initially as well and upvoted. I added an answer that works now though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   EVENT_DATE,COUNT (DISTINCT ID)
FROM     MYTABLE 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE T2 WHERE     
       T2.EVENT_DATE<MYTABLE.EVENT_DATE AND T2.ID=MYTABLE.ID)
GROUP BY EVENT_DATE
```

Comment: please check the answer if you like it

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Crap, sorry Spade.  Below is ust an example of what Spade was referring to if you wanted a zero displayed for trivial event_date entries.

I would do something along the lines of this ...

```
select 
a.event_date,
count(a.id) cnt_id
from
table_name a
left outer join 
(
    select x.id, min(x.event_date) min_event_date from table_name x
) b on 
    a.id = b.id AND 
    a.event_date = b.min_event_date
GROUP BY
a.event_date
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    mytable.event_date
    event_date_count.id,
    event_date_count.event_date_count
FROM
    mytable
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            id,
            event_date,
            COUNT(event_date) as event_date_count
        FROM
            mytable
        GROUP BY
            id,
           event_date
        ) event_date_count
    ON event_date_count.event_date = mytable.event_date
```

This would give you a resultset of the date, the id, and how many times that id was found in that date.

Unleash the power of joining on select statements with aggregates.

Comment: this will not work. Please check the question again!